# Correct absolute DOM element top/height

Tags: html, css

Below has an example https://jsfiddle.net/90ykbw8x/

I'd like B to overlap with C so I set the position to absolute. However you can easily see it doesn't overlap. With `e.getBoundingClientRect().top` I see it's roughly 3 pixels off in my real html page. How do I get the top/Y axis to be the same?

```
<div class="A">
<pre class="B">Test</pre>
<pre class="C">Test</pre>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.A pre {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: .25em;
}
.B {
  position:absolute;
  color:red;
}
.C {
  //padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `display: flex | flow-root | grid | inline-block | etc...` to account for the `<pre>` `margin`:

```css
.A {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.A pre {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: .25em;
}

.B {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <pre class="B">Test</pre>
  <pre class="C">Test</pre>
</div>
```